# Ruby on Rails scope error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a boolean field called "archive" in the table called "clients.
In the client.rb, I have:

```
scope :archived, where(:archive => true)
scope :active, where(:archive => false)
```

In my clients/index.html.erb, I have:

```
<% @clients.archived.each do |client| %>
```

But, I get the error

```
undefined method `archived' for #<Array:0x007fcb441f7d60>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Your `@clients` is an Array, not a collection of Clients. Can you post how you set the `@clients` variable? Also, what version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do something like this

```
Client.archived.find_each do |client|
```

Comment: for your information scopes are just like eigen methods in rails you can only call them with specific eigen class name